# Error with a boolean method in my app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, boolean

I am developing an app like Logo Quiz ... This is the activity, where you have to write the name of the logo:

```
public class Vie extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView img;
    EditText et;
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;
    MediaPlayer win_sound, wrong_sound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vie);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        win_sound = MediaPlayer.create(Vie.this, R.raw.win);
        wrong_sound= MediaPlayer.create(Vie.this, R.raw.wrong);

        setImageAndTagByIntent(img);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean mb = check(et, img);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (mb) {
            // Sunet toast thread
            txt.setText(title(img));
            win_sound.start();
            i.putExtra("score", "1");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

            Thread t = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.run();
                    try {
                        sleep(win_sound.getDuration());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        finish();
                    }

                }

            };

            t.start();

        }

        if (!mb) {
            // sunet toast thread
            wrong_sound.start();
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong answer! Please check if you have spelled corectly the name of the team!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }
    }

    private String title(ImageView img2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = (String) img2.getTag();
        return s;
    }

    private void setImageAndTagByIntent(ImageView img2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Trece si tagul!
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bitmap back = i.getParcelableExtra("back");
        Drawable b = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), back);
        img2.setImageDrawable(b);
        String tag = i.getStringExtra("tag");
        Object tag2 = (Object) tag;
        img2.setTag(tag2);

    }

    private boolean check(EditText et2, ImageView img2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = et2.getText().toString();
        s = WordUtils.capitalize(s);
        String s1 = (String) img2.getTag();
        boolean b;

        if ((s1.contains("") && s.contentEquals(firstWord(s1)))||(s.contentEquals(s1) && !s1.contains(""))) {
            b = true;
        }else {
            b=false;
        }



        return b;

    }


    private String firstWord(String s1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String arr[] = s1.split("//s");
        return arr[0];
    }



}
```

It works ... but when the name of the logo has two words and when I put only the first word, it says that it is wrong! It works only with the full name. Please Help Me!

Comment: where is the problem. please be more specific

Comment: if the name of the logo is "android makeup" and i put just "android"

Comment: It will say that its wrong

Comment: s1.split(" "); will work

Comment: I think your if should be like this in check method    


if ((s1.contains("") && s.contentEquals(firstWord(s1)))||(s.contentEquals(s1) && s1.contains("")))

Comment: Have a look at my answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below condition:

```
 private String firstWord(String s1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String arr[] = s1.split(" ");
    return arr[0];
}
```

Also change your if condition:

```
((s1.contains(" ") && s.contentEquals(firstWord(s1)))||(s.contentEquals(s1) && !s1.contains(" ")))
```

Comment: what is the differnce between my if statement and yours?

Comment: I dont see a space in the contains(" "), you have written it as s1.contains("");

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with your firstWord function. Try changing it to:

```
private String firstWord(String s1) {
    String arr[] = s1.split(" ");
    return arr[0];
}
```

Also, change this:

```
if ((s1.contains("") && s.contentEquals(firstWord(s1)))||(s.contentEquals(s1) && !s1.contains("")))
```

To:

```
if ((s1.contains(" ") && s.contentEquals(firstWord(s1)))||(s.contentEquals(s1) && !s1.contains(" ")))
```